# groovy: how to replaceAll ')' with ' '

Tags: groovy, replaceall

I tried this:

```
def str1="good stuff 1)"
def str2 = str1.replaceAll('\)',' ')
```

but i got the following error:

> Exception org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed, Script11.groovy: 3: unexpected char: '\' @ line 3, column 29. 1 error at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector(failIfErrors:296)

so the question is how do I do this:

```
str1.replaceAll('\)',' ')
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Same as in Java:

```
def str2 = str1.replaceAll('\\)',' ')
```

You have to escape the backslash (with another backslash).

Comment: As pointed out in another answer, in both Java and Groovy you should not use a RegEx at all and use `.replace()` instead. That solution is much faster and you don't need to care about escaping the closing bracket.

Answer (score 26):

A more Groovy way: `def str2 = str1.replaceAll(/\)/,' ')`

Answer (score 5):

You have to escape the `\` inside the `replaceAll`

```
def str2 = str1.replaceAll('\\)',' ')
```

Answer (score 3):

just use method without regex:

```
def str2 = str1.replace(')',' ')
```

Comment: This is the right way. Why create a regex if it's not necessary?

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are correct for this specific example; however, in real cases, for instance when parsing a result using `JsonSlurper` or `XmlSlurper` and then replacing a character in it, the following Exception occurs:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.replaceAll() is applicable for argument types
```

Consider the following example,

```
def result = new JsonSlurper().parseText(totalAddress.toURL().text)
```

If one wants to replace a character such as `'('` in `result` with a `' '` for example, the following returns the above `Exception`:

```
def subResult = result.replaceAll('\\(',' ')
```

This is due to the fact that the `replaceAll` method from Java works only for `string` types. For this to work, `toString()` should be added to the result of a variable defined using `def`:

```
def subResult = result.toString().replaceAll('\\[',' ')
```